# WPF Event Handler for Powershell output is never triggered

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, data-binding, event-handling

I'm working on a WPF application that executes MSTest via a PowerShellInstance. The Tests run but the output event handler is never triggered. The following is the code in my ViewModel:

```
 private void RunMSTest(string parameters)
    {

        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            string args = parameters;
            PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Start-Process");
            PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("FilePath", "mstest");
            PowerShellInstance.AddArgument(args);

            PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();

            outputCollection.DataAdded += outputCollection_DataAdded;
            PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.DataAdded += Error_DataAdded;

            IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);

            while (result.IsCompleted == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[While] Running ...");
                Model.Output = outputCollection;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Test completed! "+ PowerShellInstance.InvocationStateInfo.State);
            foreach(PSObject outputItem in outputCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Output Item" + outputItem);
            }
            PowerShellInstance.EndInvoke(result);
        }

    }
```

And my event handler in the same file:

```
private void outputCollection_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        Model.Output = sender.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("** An Item was added to the Output stream.");
    }
```

When setting break points on this event handler it is never triggered.

Comment: Why are you using powershell/runspaces for this instead of just using the `Process` class?

Comment: Actually I hadn't thought of it, kinda went down a rabbit hole and got tunnel vision. Although your suggestion works, I would still like to find a solution for the original code for knowledge sak.